# Passing parameters from JSON to PHP Excel via PHP

Tags: php, json, phpexcel

Passing parameters from JSON to PHP Excel via PHP
Are there anyways to do this?

I have already tried all sets of tutorials

https://gist.github.com/nfeldman/1432857

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple.php

https://github.com/fastfedora/google-docs/blob/master/scripts/ImportJSON/Code.gs

and checked a lot of questions and answers regarding about this but I can't find the exact code I'm looking for.

Scenario:

I have 2 json data input dynamically taken from an api

```
fruit:"WATERMELON", color:"RED";

fruit: "ORANGE", color:"ORANGE";
```

---

So, in php I want to call watermelon and red
Example code: (as per research)

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
   echo $value['fruit']; <- How to call specific fruit?
```

---

Finally, how can I call $value['fruit'] in another php file to input the data in an excel using PHPExcel.

Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you know which fruit you want to get the colour of

Comment: What is the exact JSON string you are working with. It's difficult to give you any guidance with your *pseudo-JSON*.

Comment: @Phylogenesis its a json data from an api online, https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=3bd884bb0078f836a56f1464097fb71eac9d50ce

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '
[
    "WATERMELON",
    "RED",
    "apple"
]';

$frt = json_decode($json);

echo $frt [1]; // RED
```

Comment: I wanted to know how to pass parameters from json in php to phpexcel :)